# Custom Block "Invalid Block Type"

Tags: blocks, controllers, ee-1.13, custom-block

I have a custom Block which I'm now trying to break into two sepparate blocks.

Here's my folder structure (on app/code/local/MyNamespace/CustomerDashboard):

[image]

Since I want to break the functions of this module into two smaller parts I added the files `MyMenu.php` on Block folder, and `MyMenuController.php` into controllers.

Then, I just copy/pasted the code from `Deliverydetails.php` into `MyMenu.php` and `DeliverydetailsController.php`into `MyMenuController.php` just to see if it would work.

I went into my local.xml and added the reference to my module and it's template:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="customerdashboard/mymenu" name="customerdashboard.mymenu" template="customer/form/my-menu.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

When I access the page where I should be seeing the content, there is nothing in the place where the module should be, but I went to check on the exceptions.log and found this:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block_Mymenu' in /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block type...')
#1 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('customerdashboa...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('customerdashboa...', 'customerdashboa...')
#3 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('customerdashboa...', 'customerdashboa...')
#4 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(107): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/mysite/public_html/index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

I didn't touch my config.xml nor anything else aside from the two files I already mentioned (and only to remove functionality I didn't want in this particular block) and this is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard>
                <version>0.1.1</version>
        </MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard>
    </modules>   

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customerdashboard>
                <class>MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Helper</class>
            </customerdashboard>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <customerdashboard>
                <class>MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block</class>
            </customerdashboard>
        </blocks>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <states>
                    <invoiced translate="label">
                        <label>Invoiced</label>
                        <statuses>
                            <invoced default="1"/>
                        </statuses>
                        <visible_on_front>1</visible_on_front>
                    </invoiced>
                </states>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customerdashboard>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard</module>
                    <frontName>customerdashboard</frontName>
                </args>
            </customerdashboard>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>     

</config>
```

I've read other threads on this matter here on StackExchange but didn't get any clues to what might be the problem.

So, what am I doing wrong that I can't get my block to render and I'm getting that error on my exceptions.log ? Also, I'm a Magento newb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per as magento,the `file/folder` name after `Block,Model,Helper folder` should be `start with Uppercase` and only `contain one uppercase for  each folder and files`.

According to `magento` the file name is `Mymenu` instead of `MyMenu`.

Class name should be `MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block_Mymenu`

Comment: Well, I must admit I didn't know that nor thought that would be important! Well spotted. The block is now definatly there. No content renders though, but theblock is there.. (can't upvote you yet because of rep :( )

Comment: Also.need to check class name same as .... Mymenu

Comment: I did that once you mentioned the differences between my style and megento's style. Both on the controller and on the Block. I'm checking into what else might be the problem

Comment: answer update please check

Comment: very useful answer great :)

Answer (score 2):

Your error says, it cant find the block `MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block_Mymenu`. As per this hint, Your block class should be at `app\code\local\MyNamespace\CustomerDashboard\Block\Mymenu.php`. Please note you have `MyMenu.php`. It should be `Mymenu.php`. Also you need to ensure the class name is `MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block_Mymenu`.

or

you can avoid this error by simply changing your `local.xml` update. It should look like this.

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="customerdashboard/myMenu" name="customerdashboard.mymenu" template="customer/form/my-menu.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

See the type now we are using. It is `customerdashboard/myMenu` instead of `customerdashboard/mymenu`. Now this type will refer to the block class `MyNamespace_CustomerDashboard_Block_MyMenu`. This way your block will be recongnized by Magento and problem will resolve

***Note :*** Dont forget to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (Magento 1.9), if we forgot to use construct function in block PHP file then put it and the issue will be fixed:

```
 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }
```