# How to change Shipping Method title in magento checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I want to change Shipping Method title on checkout page as shown in below image-

[image]

I tried to do following below links, but dont know which block class to overwrite.

http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Here is what I tried-

```
<blocks>
  <methods>
    <rewrite>
      <shipping_method>Emizentech_Restricteway_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method</shipping_method>
    </rewrite>
  </methods>
</blocks>
```

and created this file in my module--

**Emizentech/Restricteway/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php**

**EDIT:-**
**I want to change 'Shipping Method' title to 'unloading Method' only when my quote grand total is greater than $1100.**

Here is my updated files-
**config.xml-**

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Emizentech_Restricteway>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Emizentech_Restricteway>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <restricteway>
          <class>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block</class>
      </restricteway>
      <checkout>
          <rewrite>
              <onepage_shipping_method>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method
              </onepage_shipping_method>
          </rewrite>
      </checkout>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <restricteway>
        <class>Emizentech_Restricteway_Helper</class>
      </restricteway>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

**Emizentech/Restricteway/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php-**

```
class Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method  extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $cartGrandTotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        $conditionOrderAmount = Mage::getStoreConfig('setting/setorder/order_amount');
        if($cartGrandTotal > $conditionOrderAmount)
        {
            $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Unloading Method'),
                'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
        }
        else
        {
           $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Shipping Method 456'),
                'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
           parent::_construct();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Retrieve is allow and show block
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShow()
    {
        return !$this->getQuote()->isVirtual();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')` instead of `Mage::helper('checkout')` on line where you are getting grand total

Comment: If its still not working, use `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()` to get Grand total amount

Comment: Still Not working. And if I try  die('hello'); in construct method, it also does not work.

Comment: Can you please confirm your module is installed and enabled from System > Configuration > Advanced

Comment: Yes. It is enabled. confirmed

Comment: Please Check edits in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to update for **config.xml** like below, Change

```
<blocks>
  <methods>
    <rewrite>
      <shipping_method>Emizentech_Restricteway_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method</shipping_method>
    </rewrite>
  </methods>
</blocks>
```

to

```
<blocks>
    <restricteway>
        <class>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block</class>
    </restricteway>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_shipping_method>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method</onepage_shipping_method>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

The block file **Emizentech/Restricteway/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php** you created is also wrong, You need to create **Emizentech/Restricteway/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php** file
Now in your file, add below code.

```
class Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        if(Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() > 1100){
            $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Unloading Method'),
                'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
        }else{
            $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                 'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Shipping Method'),
                 'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
            parent::_construct();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITS:**
**app\etc\modules\Emizentech_Restricteway.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Emizentech_Restricteway>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Emizentech_Restricteway>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Emizentech\Restricteway\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Emizentech_Restricteway>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Emizentech_Restricteway>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <restricteway>
        <class>Emizentech_Restricteway_Helper</class>
      </restricteway>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <restricteway>
        <class>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block</class>
      </restricteway>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method>Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method</onepage_shipping_method>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Emizentech\Restricteway\Block\Checkout\Onepage\Shipping\Method.php**

```
<?php
class Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $cartGrandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        $conditionOrderAmount = Mage::getStoreConfig('setting/setorder/order_amount');
        if($cartGrandTotal > $conditionOrderAmount)
        {
            $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Unloading Method'),
                'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
        }
        else
        {
           $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('shipping_method', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Shipping Method 456'),
                'is_show'   => $this->isShow()
            ));
           parent::_construct();
        }

    }
}
```

This code is working for me. Please check with your code.

Comment: By following above way, Shipping Method steps has been disappeared on checkout page.

Comment: Updated code for `Emizentech/Restricteway/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Shipping/Method.php`, please check now.

Comment: Shipping Method steps has been disappeared on checkout page.

Comment: please post your updated code to question.

Comment: please check edits

Comment: I checked exception.log file and it is showing exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Emizentech_Restricteway_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method
              ' in /var/www/bulknew/app/Mage.php:595

Comment: Replace your module and use this one with same filename and code or Check for any Uppercase or Lowercase mismatch in Module name. reference http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/69603/23825

Comment: Issue was in permission in module files. Thank You Jaimin for your great support

Answer (score 2):

Change In below file if your store is English

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv
```

Change

```
"Shipping Method","Shipping Method"
```

to

```
"Shipping Method","<Your Title>"
```